# Optimizing this code to find connected components?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, graph

I have undirected graph and I need to find number of connected components of the graph. I represent graph as `Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map` (node: list of connected nodes). And then I go through that map and count connected components

```
int countComponents() {
    for (Integer u : map.keySet()) { //all nodes
        if (visited[u] == false) {
            visited[u] = true;
            components++;
            dfs(u);
        }
    }
    return components;
}

void dfs(int u) {
    for (Integer v : map.get(u)) { //v is node connected to u
        if (visited[v] == false) {
            visited[v] = true;
            dfs(v);
        }
    }
}
```

But I need more efficient algorithm. Maybe it is better to use another representation of graph or there are another ways to find number of connected components?

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm you've got here is about as fast as it gets if you don't have any prior knowledge about the connected components of the graph. (DFS runs in linear time.) If you'd like to speed things up, you'll probably only be able to do so by a constant factor unless you have some other information about the graph structure.

I'd recommend looking into the disjoint-set forest data structure, which is a really fast data structure for maintaining connected components. It's asymptotically slower than DFS, but the constant factor is pretty low and you may find it in practice to be faster than what you have here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any algorithm which would be asymptotically faster than your solution, which runs in linear times. However you could do the following to reduce the constant:

1. Use bfs rather than dfs: you pay overhead for every function call!
2. Use `int[][]` rather than `Map<Integer, ListArray<Integer>>` (probably `Map<Integer, int[]>` would be enough): Firstly the access of `int[]` is faster as the access of a `ListArray`, secondly you don't have to do the boxing/unboxing of `int` to `Integer`.